# Python: Using strings as an object argument?

Tags: python, string, object, types, type-conversion

Essentially my problem is as follows...

In Python, I have a function that will return an output string in the following form:

```
'union(symbol(a), symbol(b))'
```

The function forms found within this string actually exist in an object class called RegExTree.  Further this class contains a function to construct a tree data structure using the function "construct()" as shown below:

```
tree = RegExTree()    
tree.construct(union(symbol(a), symbol(b))
```

The above two lines of code would work normally, constructing a tree based on parsing the arguments within the construct function.  I want to pass in a string in a similar fashion, perhaps this line of code illustrates what I want:

```
tree = RegExTree()      
expression = 'union(' + 'symbol(' + 'a' + ')' + ', ' +  'symbol(' + 'b' + ')' + ')'
tree.construct(expression)
```

Right now the way I have the code written as above it yields an error (in the Linux terminal) as follows:

```
$ Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Can you coerce Python to interpret the string as a valid argument/line of code.  In essence, not as string, but as object constructors.

Is there a way to get Python to interpret a string as rather something that would have been parsed/compiled into objects and have it construct the objects from the string as if it were a line of code meant to describe the same end goal?
Is what I'm asking for some kind of back-door type conversion?  Or is what I'm asking not possible in programming languages, specifically Python?

EDIT:  Using Michael's solution posited below that involves "eval()", there is one way to hack this into form:

```
tree = RegExTree()
a = 'a'
b = 'b'    
expression = 'union(' + 'symbol(' + a + ')' + ', ' +  'symbol(' + b + ')' + ')'
tree.construct(eval(expression))
```

Is there a better way of doing this?  Or is it just that the nature of my output as string representing functions is just not a good idea?
[Thanks martineau for the correction for my solution edit!]

Comment: You can use the `eval` function to evaluate an expression in a string, but yes, it is a bit of a back door.  There is probably a better way.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why is your function returning strings? You should be passing around functions instead. Evaluating strings is probably not the way to do it

Comment: The algorithm that created the string output is recursive in nature and it's purpose is to generate a completely randomized "regular expression" in the format I show above [i.e. union(x,y) represents x U y).  Essentially, for every argument spot in a function, that could potentially be another function call.  Take for example:  union(x, y) could potentially be x = union(a,b) and y = star(c), yielding union(union(a,b), star(c))

Comment: Still, you could use something like this: `def lazy_apply(x, *args): return lambda: x(*args)` to construct complex objects without resorting to switching to strings.

Comment: In your edit all you really needed to do was `a = 'a'` and `b = 'b'` to get it to work (assuming those are the values you want `a` and `b` to have when `symbol()` is called).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the python built-in [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) statement.

A word of caution though... you do not want to run `eval()` on a string that's coming into your program as external input provided by the user. That could create a security hole where users of your program could run arbitrary Python code of their own design.

In your example it'd look something like this:

```
tree = RegExTree()      
expression = 'union(' + 'symbol(' + 'a' + ')' + ', ' +  'symbol(' + 'b' + ')' + ')'
tree.construct( eval(expression) ) # Notice the eval statement here
```

Comment: This is a great idea!  And almost worked, but it seems to not like the argument char a or char b, however, as now I get the error: 
$ NameError: name a is not defined

Comment: Actually, your solution works but with one slight modification I will post in the question above as an edit.

Comment: Why not just write `expression = 'union(symbol(a), symbol(b)'`? Note that all the names used: `union`, `symbol`, `a`, and `b` will have to be defined before `eval()` is called or a `NameError` exception will be raised.

Comment: One other option (but it's a bit more work) is that instead of building strings, you build AST nodes (have a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) and compile that to a code object, then pass/call that where needed...